# after concatinating two variables, first isn't shown when uploaded to wordpress site

Tags: bash

I'm using a mixture of bash and php to automate uploading posts to wordpress. Long story short inside body I want to have youtube video first and then underneath will be rest of the post. once passed onto php which that uploaded everything to my website, I noticed that video isn't included in my new post. Obviously I booted up my debugger and from [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEnO3.png) you can see that everything is the way that it's supposed to be. Header is there, categories and body with both video and content are there. Please if someone could tell me what I am missing because I'm lost. thank you

```
#!/bin/bash



count=0
length=$(cat scripttest/content/tTestjSON.json | ./jq 'length')
video=$(./jq ".[$count].video"< scripttest/content/tTestjSON.json)
video2="<iframe width='560' height='315' src=$video frameborder='0' gesture='media' allow='encrypted-media' allowfullscreen></iframe>"

head=$(./jq ".[$count].head"< scripttest/content/tTestjSON.json)
head2="${head#\"}"
head2="${head2%\"}"

body=$(./jq ".[$count].body"< scripttest/content/tTestjSON.json)
body2="${body#\"}"
body2="${body2%\"}"
body2="$video2$body2"

category=$(./jq ".[$count].category"< scripttest/content/tTestjSON.json)
category2="${category#\"}"
category2="${category2%\"}"
php test.php "$head2" "$body2" "$category2"
(( count++ ))
done
```

Comment: use `jq -r ...` if you don't want the result quoted.

Comment: Looks like the right arguments are being passed to the php script. I'd conclude the problem is in test.php

Comment: @glennjackman php is taken from this tutorial with small changes that instead of hardcoding all the variables, most are accepted as parameters https://www.kickstartcommerce.com/programmatically-create-wordpress-posts-pages-using-php.html